# Angular 2 / ASP.NET Core *ngFor loop issue

Tags: asp.net-core, angular2-ngfor

I am having problems displaying information from an database to the angular 2 *ngFor loop. This is my code so far:

**.Net Core controller:**

```
     // GET: api/Hats
    [HttpGet("GetHats")]
    public IEnumerable<Hat> GetHats()
    {
        return _context.Hat;
    }
```

**hat-list.component.ts:**

```
    //Imports from @Angular
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

//Other imports
import { HatListService } from '../service/service.component';
import Hat = App.Models.IHat;
//Component Config
@Component({
    selector: 'hat-list',
    templateUrl: './hat-list.component.html',
     providers: [HatListService]
})
//Class
export class HatListComponent implements OnInit {

    public Hats: any[];
    constructor(public _hatListService: HatListService) {

    }


    //OnInit
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getAllHats();
    }

    //Get All 
    getAllHats() {
        //debugger
        this._hatListService.getHatList().subscribe(foundHats =>
            this.Hats = foundHats
        );
    }
}
```

**service.component.ts**

```
//imports from Angular
import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Request, RequestMethod, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
//Other imports
import Hat = App.Models.IHat;
@Component({
    providers: [Http]
})
//Exported class
@Injectable()
export class HatListService {

    public headers: Headers;

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }

    public _getUrl: string = '/api/Hats/GetHats';

    //Get
    getHatList(): Observable<Hat[]> {
        //debugger
        return this._http.get(this._getUrl).map(res => <Hat[]>res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }


    private handleError(error: Response) {
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Opps!! Server error');
    }
}
```

**hat-list.component.html:**

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped table-responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Color</th>
            <th>Count</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let hat of Hats"">

            <td>{{hat.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{hat.Color}}</td>
            <td>{{hat.Count}}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" (click)="delete(hat)"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Picture of the table**
[image]

**The *ngFor recives the value.**

[image]

I know the request to the database happens asynch and that one problem might be that the *ngfor loop fires before the data has returned and thus no information is displayed. But diffrent articles on the net say that the *ngFor loop shouldt fire unless the iterable has a value. The strange thing is that when I update the database manually thru SSMS the *ngfor recognises the added content add creates additioanl rows. What am I doing wrong.

**Thanx for all the help!**

Comment: Can you show your `Hat` class? Not sure for 100% but I guess the issue is that you use incorrect names of your variables i.e. `{{hat.Name}}` instead of `{{hat.name}}`.

Comment: Soory for the awful formatting. Tried to format as code`

declare module App.Models {

    interface IHat {
        Id: number;
        Name: string;
        Color: string;
        Count: number;
    }

}`

Comment: You have my biggest thanx sir!!. Such a noobie mistake. changed the interface properties to small staring letters. The it worked.

Comment: add the letters in the html file ofcourse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are wrong variable names used in the template i.e. `{{hat.Name}}` instead of `{{hat.name}}`.